# How to automate library upgrades from one project to other

Tags: continuous-integration, pipeline

I am trying to see what are some best practices that can be adapted to reduce the mess. Let me put forward a scenario

- `projectA` owns `contract.proto` file.
- `projectB` use a *copy* of `contract.proto` file to communicate with `projectA`

Now the problem here is that whenever `projectA` has to make a change (let's assume that all these changes are additive changes) in `contract.proto` file, those changes needs to be copied with in `projectB`.

We use *CircleCI* to deploy our projects and what I am looking for that is there a better way to merge changes from `projectA` to `projectB` automatically?

Comment: If `contract.proto` is a code library, then you can use a dependency manager suitable for the language it is written in. It can go in its own repo, and then all projects fetch it as part of their build process.

Comment: (I've edited the tags, as this is not related to CircleCI, deployment or CD).